# How to update cell output of a jupyter notebook which is hosted on a network IP

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I have a problem with a jupyter notebook that I have on a raspberry pi and am hosting on our IP address.

To do this, I used `jupyter notebook --generate-config` to generate the configuration file, where I then edited the `c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'` to the IP address of our network. The jupyter notebook should display live results from measurements I do with different microprocessors.

The access to the home page is working great, and I can download the log files that I am generating. In the main file, however, I can see that it is being executed, but the values are not changing with time. The value is currently frozen at around 15:49:14, which is when I closed the first notebook where I started the execution.

The problem is happening so far with three laptops and even on the raspberry pi itself.

I found this closed GitHub issue: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/83

It was closed due to inactivity

All my packages are up to date on all sides, as I built the whole system not long ago, and I ensured everything was stable. One of the laptops I tried was a Linux and it also did not work.

Could something in the configuration file still need to be adjusted?

Comment: The issue you reference at https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/83 wasn't closed due to inactivity. It was initially but was reopened. Why it was ultimately closed is explained way at the bottom [there](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/83#issuecomment-1852834573). Anyway, like the last post says there are some gems in there and insight into what is going on. Did any of [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/83#issuecomment-1501093170) help you?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try some of the solutions out and see if they will work. Have never worked with the chrome dev tools, so a stupid question: do I need chrome for that? Currently running everything with Mozilla

Comment: There's probably tools in Mozilla's stuff. However, it may not exactly correspond and so investigating the way described would be much easier than looking into how to do the equivalent thing.

Comment: @Wayne I played around today and I realized I can workaround my problem by writing another notebook

Comment: Glad you found something amenable to your needs. Thanks for posting it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am saving all the data to a file anyway, I decided to write another notebook on the same server that opens the file and gets the measured points. It is not actually a solution to my question, but rather a quick workaround.

The advantage is that I don't have to disturb the measurement notebook, whenever I want, I can open the other notebook and have nice plots and summaries